# If row contains value, return value from column A value, for all rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've seen some similar posts, but none with a really helpful answer for my particular issue. I'm a programmatic advertising data analyst, so i'm trying to associate a many-to-many relationship.

We run "personas", which is a group of apps. A persona has many apps, and apps have many personas. I have the data organized by persona: each row is a persona, and each column in that row contains one of the apps comprising that persona. Each persona has a different number of apps. i.e.

```
Row   Persona            App 1            App 2             App 3           
1   Casino Persona    "Slot Kings"    "Wild Casino"   "Real Gambling App"
2   RPG Persona      "Dragon Valor"      "KOTOR"
3   Sports Persona   "MLB: The App"   "Real Soccer"   "Hockey Fans 2016"
4   Gen-X Females    "Scrapbook App"  "Baby Monitor"     "PostMates"
```

So i know which apps belong to each persona. I'm now trying to determine which personas belong to each app. I'd like to create another worksheet that switches "apps" and "personas." e.g.

```
Row    App          Persona 1         Persona 2          Persona 3           
1   Slot Kings    "Casino Persona"  "Slot Persona"   
2   KOTOR         "RPG Persona"     "Star Wars Fans"   "SciFi Persona"
3   MLB: The App  "Sports Persona"  "Baseball Fans"
```

I can't figure out any way to do this an insane nested statement, VBA, or a similarly crazy array formula.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your broken attempt(s) - as it stands your question is *too broad* to be answerable: it basically boils down to "here are some specs, please implement it for me"

Comment: Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more on how to restructure your question to receive more help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're asking for. However, trying to rearrange your data with either formulas or VBA would take a lot of time and effort; and is also quite unnecessary.

The layout of your data is good for viewing, but is not suitable for any kind of data analysis. If you want to perform analysis, data should always be stored in a database format. See this article for more info:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-for-organizing-and-formatting-data-on-a-worksheet-90895CAD-6C85-4E02-90D3-8798660166E3

For your data, you should just have 2 columns, one for Persona and one for App. Then on every row, you list just one possible combination of Persona and App. It doesn't matter in what order you place the data.

With your data set up correctly, you can now create PivotTables that automatically arrange your data either way. It's also possible to easily count the number of apps in each persona and vice versa and then also create charts. Look up PivotTables and PivotCharts for more info.

To create the top left table, put Persona into the Rows field and then put App into Rows field as well. (Turn off subtotals and totals to make the table neater, and change the layout to Tabular to see the field names.)

To create the top right table, put App into the Data field instead.

To create the bottom tables, add the fields in the opposite order.

[image]

Note that if you have more details about either personas or apps that you want to record, they should be stored in separate tables. This is now getting into the realm of designing a relational database. Look for references on database design for more information.

Comment: Narrow vs. wide data. of course! Can't believe i didn't see the forest from the trees. Thanks!

Comment: No worries and you're welcome. If this solves your problem, can you please mark this answer as correct to resolve the question? Otherwise let us know if you need anything further. Thanks.